# Colouring Positive Integers

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Does anyone know any reference or proof for the following problem?

> Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers, $m,n \geq 2$. Each positive integer is coloured in one of $m$ different colours. Is it possible to find $n$ positive integers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ such that all positive numbers of the form $$\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_ix_i,$$ where $\epsilon_i \in \{0,1\},$ have the same colour, when:
>
> a) $n \leq m$?
> b) $n>m$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  This is a weak form of Hindman's theorem. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_set .

Answer (score 4):

We understand completely which finite homogeneous linear structures are guaranteed to appear in one colour class whenever the natural numbers are finitely coloured.  Suppose first that we'd like to find a monochromatic solution to $Ax=0$ where $A$ has rational entries.  [Rado proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado%27s_theorem_(Ramsey_theory)) that this is possible if and only if $A$ has the *columns property*.  Write $A = \begin{pmatrix}c^{(1)} & \cdots & c^{(n)}\end{pmatrix}$.  Then $A$ has the columns property if and only if there is a partition $[n] = I_1 \cup \cdots \cup I_t$ such that

- $\sum_{i \in I_1} c^{(i)} = 0$, and
- $\sum_{i \in I_s} c^{(i)} \in \langle c^{(j)} : j \in I_1 \cup \cdots \cup I_{s-1}\rangle$,

where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denotes rational linear span.

Your problem has this form by taking $A$ to be the matrix corresponding to the equations
$$
y_I = \sum_{i \in I} x_i
$$
for each $\emptyset \subset I \subseteq [n]$.  This matrix has a block structure, with $-1$ times the $(2^n-1) \times (2^n-1)$ identity matrix in the left half and a $(2^n-1) \times n$ right half with all non-zero rows containing only $1$'s and $0$'s.  It's easy to check that this matrix has the columns property.

We were lucky here that the expressions you wanted to be monochromatic included the single variables $x_i$, allowing the problem to be rephrased in terms of a monochromatic solution to a system of linear equations.  We might reasonably seek monochromatic structures of the form $Ax$, where we care only about the colours of the entries of the image vector, and not $x$ itself.  The situation is closely related to Rado's theorem but more complicated; the first necessary and sufficient conditions were described by [Hindman and Leader](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0963548300000821).